# Semi direct product group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Suppose $G=V \rtimes M$, is a semi product group of an elementary abelian p-group of size $|V|=p^e$ and $M$
is a subgroup of $G$. If $f$ is the natural projection from $G$ onto $M$. 
$C_x=\{x^G\}$ is a conjugacy class.
I would like to prove $|f^{-1}(m)\cap C_x|\geq p, m\in M$. Do you think such result is true?
Best regards
Ha.

Comment: Shouldn't you assume $e > 0$?

Answer (score 1):

In general it is false.  Let $M$ be abelian and act trivially on $V$.  Then $G$
is just the product of $M$ and $V$ so $G$ is commutative.  Then $C_x$ contains only one element.